# How to assign different values from a string to new column?

Tags: python, pandas

Dialog_act is my label

[image]

I need to assign int values, like (inform_pricerange=1, inform_area=2, request_food=3, inform_food=4...)
The goal is to look like this:

```
1,2    
1,2,3    
4    
5,2,4    
6
```

CSV (5 rows):

```
"transcript_id  who transcript  dialog_act    
0   USR  I need to find an expensive restauant that's in the south section of the city.     inform_pricerange; inform_area;    
1   SYS  There are several restaurants in the south part of town that serve expensive food. Do you have a cuisine preference?   inform_pricerange; inform_area; request_food;    
2   USR  No I don't care about the type of cuisine.     inform_food;    
3   SYS  Chiquito Restaurant Bar is a Mexican restaurant located in the south part of town.     inform_name; inform_area; inform_food;    
4   USR  What is their address?     request_address;    
5   SYS  There address is 2G Cambridge Leisure Park Cherry Hinton Road Cherry Hinton, it there anything else I can help you with?   inform_address;"
```

How can i do that?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Can you post the code to reproduce the dataframe, [as opposed to an image of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: The dataframe came from a csv file, just like that

Comment: Please replace your image by the plain text data.

Comment: but it's only " df_full = pd.read_csv(csvFile)"

Comment: Copy/Paste the content of your file (the five first rows)

Comment: okey, i've done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> I want to define the values, not in ascending order

```
vals_to_replace = {'inform_pricerange': 1, 'inform_area': 2, 'request_food': 3,
                   'inform_food': 4, 'inform_name': 5, 'request_address': 6,
                   'inform_address': 7}

df['dialog_act'] = df['dialog_act'].str.strip(';').str.split('; ').explode() \
                      .map(vals_to_replace).astype(str) \
                      .groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join)
print(df)

# Output
  dialog_act
0       1, 2
1    1, 2, 3
2          4
3    5, 2, 4
4          6
5          7
```

---

**Old answer**

Try to `explode` your column into a list of scalar values and use `pd.factorize`

```
# Step 1: explode
df1 = df['dialog_act'].str.strip(';').str.split('; ').explode().to_frame()

# Step 2: factorize
df['dialog_act'] = df1.assign(dialog_act=pd.factorize(df1['dialog_act'])[0] + 1) \
                      .astype(str).groupby(level=0)['dialog_act'].apply(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  dialog_act
0       1, 2
1    1, 2, 3
2          4
3    5, 2, 4
4          6
5          7

>>> df1
          dialog_act
0  inform_pricerange
0        inform_area
1  inform_pricerange
1        inform_area
1       request_food
2        inform_food
3        inform_name
3        inform_area
3        inform_food
4    request_address
5     inform_address
```

Comment: not like that, because i want to define the values, not in ascending order

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Pandas `dataframe.replace()` method. Firstly, convert your table to Pandas Dataframe. Then ,

```
vals_to_replace = {'inform_pricerange':1, 'inform_area':2, 'request_food':3, 'inform_food': 4}
your_df = your_df.replace({'your_label':vals_to_replace})
```

I saw a similar question about [pandas replace multiple values one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100130/pandas-replace-multiple-values-one-column/52119719) .

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work, because i have more than 1 label per row