# How do I change abbreviated words in a column in Python, eg NY to New York, US to United States at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I replace all abbreviation in a column to word eg NY to New York, US to United States etal. I could do for just NY with inplace=True, but I need to collectively do for all abbreviations.

I tried df['prod_state'].replace('NY', 'New York', inplace= True), it worked but when I included US, errors started popping

Comment: Hi, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `pandas.map` can do bulk replacements using a dictionary, if you are matching the entire column.  If you need substrings, then there is no way to do it in bulk.

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we don't know what "errors started popping" nor can we reproduce your results.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100130/pandas-replace-multiple-values-one-column

Comment: [The `replace()` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) says that the `to_replace` and `value` arguments can be lists of the same length, and elements in the first list will be replaced with the element at the same index in the second list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) that accept dictionnaries as an argument of `to_replace`:

```
dico_abbrv= {'NY': 'New York', 'US': 'United States'}

df['prod_state'].replace(dico_abbrv, inplace= True)
```

You can also use [**`pandas.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
df['prod_state']= df['prod_state'].map(dico_abbrv)
```